# Delete and Update Trigger Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a problem with a delete and update triggers in SQL Server.

I have triggers setup for Delete, Insert, and Update on many of my tables that are used for auditing changes and they are all working fabulously, but have been trying to add some to a table I didn't previously include in my tracking.

The code for the delete trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tblSAP_Delete]
ON [dbo].[tblSAP]
AFTER DELETE AS
INSERT INTO
    tblSAPAudit (
        vchrAction,
        vchrUser,
        vchrActionDate,
        vchrDoor,
        vchrSAPCode,
        dtmStartDate,
        dtmEndDate,
        intDoorSAPID
    )
SELECT
    'Delete',
    USER_NAME(),
    GETDATE(),
    vchrDoor,
    vchrSAPCode,
    dtmStartDate,
    dtmEndDate,
    intDoorSAPID
FROM
    Deleted
```

I used the same code for the three triggers just modifying the fields and tables it was inserting to. The insert is working fine, but the Delete and Update are giving me errors when I delete a row saying

> The Row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows(2 rows).

I get that for any update or delete I try to test until I turn off the trigger. Any clue as to what I might be missing?

Comment: Can you show us your trigger code? Also: are you aware that triggers in SQL Server are **NOT** called per row - but once for a statement, and therefore, the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables will most likely include **multiple rows**. Have you taken that into account when writing your triggers?

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tblSAP_Delete] ON [dbo].[tblSAP]
AFTER DELETE AS 
INSERT INTO tblSAPAudit(vchrAction, vchrUser, vchrActionDate
 , vchrDoor, vchrSAPCode, dtmStartDate, dtmEndDate, intDoorSAPID)
 SELECT 'Delete', USER_NAME(), GETDATE()
 , vchrDoor, vchrSAPCode, dtmStartDate, dtmEndDate,  intDoorSAPID
 FROM Deleted

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: What is the PK of the table?

Comment: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/dealing-with-the-row-value-s-updated-or

Comment: Any chance you have a trigger on `tblSAPAudit`?

Comment: There is no trigger on tblSAPAudit.  THe PK is intDOorSAPID on the main table.